# Piping variable into seq_along within lapply

Tags: r, pipe, lapply

I'm abusing lapply to create stacked for-loops and sometimes I need indices rather than the list elements themselves.

Imagine something like this:

```
df <- lapply(1:5, print)
```

now if I want to print the indices I can do this:

```
invisible(lapply(seq_along(df), print))
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
```

But if I use a pipe I get an error:

```
df %>% lapply(seq_along(.), print)

Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'seq_along(.)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

This forces me to break up some pipes which is not a huge problem but I dislike it.
If there is a more elegant solution (which I'm sure there is) I couldn't find one.

---

EDIT: (for clarification as asked by @PaulS)

In my project I have a true/false list I want to make into a true/false matrix (or data frame).
As you can see if you use the dput() below, the lists have different lengths.

Since I need to tell the matrix function how many columns it needs to partition the sub-lists into I need the indices **as well as** the list elements)

Before incorporating @sindri_baldur's comment I had a true/false list (with sub lists) which I had to store in the global env. instead of continuing the pipe.

```
ta5 <- c(5,5,5,5) # this vector may be c(5,6,5,7) - never less than 5 but without upper limit

t_f_list <- lapply(1:5, function(x) do something)

new_df<-lapply(seq(t_f_list),                                                                       
               function(x) sapply(t_f_list[[x]], 
                                  function(y) y[[1]] %>% 
                                    matrix(ncol = length(.)/ta5[x]) %>% 
                                    rowSums)
```

now I'd like to be able to do this:

```
t_f_list <- lapply(some_list, function(x) do_something) %>% 
  lapply(seq(.),                                                                       
         function(x) sapply(.[[x]], 
                            function(y) y[[1]] %>% 
                              matrix(ncol = length(.)/ta5[x]) %>%
                              rowSums))
```

dput of t_f_list:

```
tf_list <- list(structure(list(tf = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)), structure(list(tf = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)), structure(list(
    tf = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)), structure(list(tf = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)), structure(list(
    tf = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)), structure(list(tf = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L)))
```

Comment: You could: `df %>% {invisible(lapply(seq_along(.), print))} `

Comment: By your own admission, you are "abusing" `lpapply`, which makes me wonder if this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Limney you may be right but in my current case I am not sure how to ask this since my code is quite long and does quite a few steps - which makes asking for a better process rather impractical.

Comment: @sindri_baldur genius! So straight forward and obvious. does exactly as i hoped. thanks!

Comment: @D.J: Notice that my solution is totally equivalent to sindri_baldur's one!

Comment: @PaulS In the simple case it is. But if i need both the data and the index it is not. Your solution was basically the first thing I tried (long time ago on a different project). This is why is expanded my question after you asked me to. I can see why you wanted me to elaborate though as my question may have been oversimplified.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% seq_along %>% lapply(print) %>% invisible

#> [1] 1
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 4
#> [1] 5
```

Comment: sadly it is not because i still need the list element, is just need to match it to some outside data (like names or geometries) so while this is of course possible, it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? It is not clear to me what you want.